# Virtual box guest addition missing and can't be downloaded

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I downloaded VirtualBox from ubuntu software center and install there **windows XP 32 bit**. Now when I'm trying to install guest additions it's saying that guest addition is missing and is asking download it. When I press 'download' it's saying that it can't download because the link is missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the console, and run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
   ```
2. Start the virtual machine (e.g. Windows XP)
3. Press <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to load the guest additions into your virtual machine.

Comment: Worth noting the package was renamed to `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04:

1. Open machine settings and select the iso file as below:
   [image]
2. You can download it by yourself or find it in /usr/share/virtualbox
3. Restart machine and try again

Answer (score 1):

You have to download guest additions from ubuntu Software Center as well if You have gained VB from USC. however it is highly recommended to download Virtual Box, Guest Additions And Extension Pack directly from [Oracle website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), as it is newer version.

Comment: And here's the link: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

Answer (score 1):

guess additions has been moved in VirtualBox 6, now the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```